# SSRS - Process dies/goes to sleep after not being used

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Another SSRS question here:   
We have a development, a QA, a Prod-Backup and a Production SSRS set of servers.   
On our production and prod-backup, SSRS will go to sleep if not used for a period of time. 
This does not occur on our development or QA server. 

In the corporate environment we're in, we don't have physical (or even remote login) access to these machines, and have to work with a team of remote administrators to configure our SSRS application.

 We have asked that they fix, if possible, this issue.    So far, they haven't been able to identify the issue, and I would like to know if any of my peers know the answer to this question.  Thanks.

Answer (score 24):

For anybody using the integrated webserver that is built into SQL Reporting Services (and hence IIS may not even be installed on the box), the setting to control this actually lives in:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\
         MSRS10_50.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\ReportServer\rsreportserver.config
```

Your directory may be different; version 10_50 maps to SQL 2008 R2.

You'll be looking for the setting called `RecycleTime`. 
Default is 720 (12 hours). Setting it to 0 will disable.

Comment: I think it should not be the answer. RecycleTime is about recycling the process after a while (which is a good practice to keep the process healthy) and it is not about shutdown or suspend the process if there is no any request (like what we control by "Idle Time-out" in IIS)

Comment: @Lynn Do that need to restart the SQL Report service to take its effect?

Comment: @meekash55 I would expect to need to.

Answer (score 2):

In IIS, check the settings on the application pool that SSRS is running in. On the properties pane->Performance tab you can set the amount of time the worker process needs to be idle for before it shuts down. You can also disable this entirely.

Answer (score 0):

I vaguely recall having problems with SSRS on one machine when we changed the "Enable HTTP Keep-Alives" setting in IIS. Try toggling that checkbox (I don't remember whether it was checked or unchecked when it caused us problems).