# How can I stop SQL Server Reporting Services 2008 going to sleep?

Tags: iis, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have SSRS 2008 set-up on a server.  All works fine except that if left inactive for a length of time the next time a request is made to the server it takes a long time for it to service it.

I think this is to do with the worker process being shutdown after being idle for a certain length of time.  However, as SSRS 2008 isn't managed through IIS I can't find any settings that I can adjust to stop this from happening.  In IIS I'd go to the Performance tab of the Application Pool Properties and choose not to shutdown the worker process.  How can I do this for SSRS 2008?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a report that does nothing.
Set a subscription up so that it runs every 'timeout problem duration - 1 minutes'

Comment: Thanks for that adolf - that's what I've done.  Works a charm.  Cheers

Answer (score 0):

The service process in SSRS 2008 can be configured using the [**RSReportServer configuration file**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157273.aspx). However I couldn't find any setting in there that controls the idle shutdown timeout.

I guess your only option to keep SSRS from going idle is to have an external process that "pings" it at regular intervals. You could for example post an HTTP request to the Report Manager web application.

Comment: Thanks Enrico - its unfortunate that there doesn't appear to be any setting for that.  I think I may have to do what you suggest and "ping" it occasionally.  Cheers

Answer (score -1):

I know this answer is fairly old, but I stumbled upon some collaborating information in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10721575/1245766). It mentions the RSReportServer configuration file, but more specifically, the `RecycleTime` setting. By setting it to 0, it should disable the 'sleep' "feature".