# Why does SSRS need to recycle the application domain

Tags: reporting-services

I'm working with MS Reporting Services 2016. I noticed that the [application domain is set by default to recycle every 12 hours](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-server/application-domains-for-report-server-applications). Now the impact on users after a recycle is either slow response from reporting services or a failed report. Both disappear after a refresh of the report, but this is not ideal.

I have come across a SO answer where people suggest that [you can turn off the scheduled recycle by setting the configuration attribute `RecycleTime` to zero](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10721575/532489).

I have also read that writing a script to [manually restart reporting services](https://community.dynamics.com/ax/f/33/t/195637), which also recycles the app domain. Then a [script that simply loads a report at a controlled time](http://thesqlgirl.com/2016/08/17/ssrs-reporting-server-recycle-time/) to remove the first time load issues. However this all seems like a work around to me and I would rather not have to do this.

My concern is that there must be a logical reason for having the scheduled recycle time, but I cannot find any information explaining this. Does anyone know if there is a negative impact from turning off the scheduled application domain recycle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `RecycleTime` is a function aimed at making sure SSRS isn't consuming RAM it doesn't need and potentially starving the rest of the machine.  Disabling the refresh essentially removes the ability to claw back any memory used for a brief period of intensive processing.

If you are confident your machine is suitably resourced you can turn the refresh off or, if not, alternatively schedule the refresh for an out of hours time and define a `Cache Refresh Plan` to cache any super important reports immediately afterwards to minimise any user impact.

Further reading here: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2735/prevent-sql-server-reporting-services-slow-startup/

Answer (score 2):

I guess I'm possibly over simplifying this, but SSRS was designed to recycle every 12 hours (default) for a reason.  If it ain't broke, don't fix it.  In my case, I wanted to control when the recycle occurred.  I execute a 1 line powershell script from a SQL Agent job at 6:50 am, then generate a subscription report at 7 am, which kick starts SSRS and the users do not see any performance degradation.

**restart-service 'ReportServer'**

Leaving the SSRS config file setting at 720 minutes lets the recycle occur again at 6:50 pm.  Subscription reports generate throughout the night, so if a human gets on SSRS after hours there should be no performance issue because the system is already running.

Are we possibly overthinking it?